# Boundedness of a stochastic process and martingale convergence

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I am working on an exercise that asks me to prove the boundedness of the following stochastic process:

Let $X_i$ be iid r.v. s.t. $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=1/2$

Let $S_n = X_1+\ldots+X_n, n\in \mathbb{N}$

Let $\alpha>0$ and let $Z_n = (\exp(S_n-\alpha n)), n\in \mathbb{N}$

How can I show that $|Z_{n+1}-Z_n|<=k, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?

I tried different approaches but I keep getting stuck. I do know that $S_n$ makes "jumps" of at most $1$ while $\alpha\cdot n$ makes jumps of size at most $\alpha$ but since the exponential is there I am not sure how this translates into a boundedness of the difference between the two exponentials. Passing to the logarithm doesn't help because of the minus sign in the middle (or at least I think).
I also thought that $$\frac{\exp(S_{n+1})}{\exp(S_n)}\leq e \implies \exp(S_{n+1})\leq\exp(S_n+1).$$
There probably is some (in)equality that I don't know, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $|Z_{n+1} - Z_n| \in \{ |\exp(1-\alpha)-1|Z_n, |\exp(-1-\alpha)-1|Z_n\}$ by looking at the possible values of $X_{n+1}$. In particular, if $X_{n+1} = 1$ then $|Z_{n+1} - Z_n| = |\exp(1-\alpha)-1|Z_n$.

Suppose $\alpha < 1$ and there is a $k$ such that for every $n$, $|Z_{n+1} - Z_n| \leq k$ with probability $1$. Pick $n$ sufficiently large, so that $$\exp((1-\alpha)n) > \frac{k}{|\exp(1-\alpha)-1|}.$$
Then with probability $2^{-(n+1)}$, $X_k = 1$ for $k = 1, \dots, n+1$. In particular, with positive probability $S_{n+1} = n+1, X_{n+1} = 1$ and hence $$|Z_{n+1} - Z_n| = |\exp(1-\alpha)-1| \exp((1-\alpha)n) > k$$
so that the result you stated doesn't hold.

If $\alpha \geq 1$ then notice that $S_n \leq n$ implies that $Z_n = \exp(S_n - \alpha n) \leq \exp((1-\alpha)n) \leq 1$. Hence, in this case, $|Z_{n+1} - Z_n| \leq Z_{n+1} + Z_n \leq 2$.

Comment: I am sorry but now that I read your answer more carefully I have a few questions: first of all the first request (of the exercise) was to make sure that $Z_n$ is a martingale and it is true for $\alpha=\log(\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2})$. That would make $\alpha<1$ and the increases of the martingale potentially unbounded according to your analysis (which should not be the case, as it asks to apply the martingale convergence theorem (implicitly)). Also, how can $X_{n+1}=n+1$ if it can be only $-1,1$? @RhysSteele

Comment: I would recommend that you ask the edit as a new question rather than just entirely changing the nature of this question once you've already received an answer. You've shown that $Z_n$ is a martingale iff $\alpha = \frac12(e + e^{-1})$. Using this martingale to compute the expectation you want is a different thing entirely (but I also really don't see why martingale convergence would be relevant to that either tbh).

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will!